# Need Help Solving this in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

Need help IN SAS
What SAS query will produce the unique list of student names and their average grade, excluding students who were in detention, using the following tables?

- Students

```
Student_ID  Student_Name
12345   Bob
23456   Sally
34567   Joe
…   …
```

- Grades

```
Student_ID  Class_ID    Grade
12345   SCI 75%
12345   MTH 68%
34567   PHY 89%
…   …   …
```

- Detention

```
Student_ID
23456
89123
78912
…
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sql noprint; 
create table scores as 
select student_id, avg(grade) as AVG from secondtable
where Student_id not in(select student_id from third table) 
group by student_id; quit;
```

When you provide so little information it will be hard for most people to help you.  Two things you could do to improve your question:

1. add more complete sample data.  We don't need the entire tables but provide enough data so people can test the code. (no images)
2. show what you have tried.  Stackoverflow police get very sensitive about this.

Comment: it looks like you accepted the answer and then uncheck it.  Is it not working for you?